# mySQL Restrict Cascade No Action settings

Tags: mysql, cascade, restrict

What is the best constraint to use on a forum table where users leave comments?

Assuming some users will be deleted at a later stage. if i delete a user who has commented, what happens to the users entry in the table?

Hope someone can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

1. how best to implement this?  You can "soft-delete" user rows.  This has the advantages of:

   - not losing user information
   - allowing users to be un-deleted
   - maintaining referential integrity without losing data linked to users

   Soft-deleting can be implemented by adding another column to the users table, with a `dateDeleted` column -- if it's Null, then the user isn't deleted.  I believe SO uses such a mechanism for deleting posts.
2. what does `restrict cascade no action` do?  The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) say

> - RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table.
>     Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON
>     DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.
> - NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to
>     RESTRICT. InnoDB rejects the delete or update operation for the parent
>     table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table.
>     Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a
>     deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked
>     immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

In other words, if you use this, you won't be able delete rows if doing so would break referential integrity.

Comment: Many thanks for that. so which constraint is the best to use for the first option you gave for ON UPDATE and ON DELETE?

Comment: @olad if you're using `InnoDB` as your storage engine, foreign keys will automatically be enforced.  So the defaults for `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` are fine, since you won't (or at least, shouldn't) be changing the primary keys of rows.